# Print items from list which listed in another list

Tags: python

I have 3 lists which i need to use some of them for further use based on condition. Example are as below:

```
d_list = ['a', 'b', 'c']
m_list = ['d', 'e', 'f']
q_list = ['g', 'h', 'i']
```

masterlist = ['d_list','m_list','q_list']

Lets assume d,m,q from list names are load types. If I pass load type as d, it should print m_list and q_list i.e

```
'd'
'e'
'f'
'g'
'h'
'i'
```

Code which i tried

```
all_cols = ['("'+' '.join(item)+'")' for list in masterlist if not list.startswith(loadtype)]

Result was
["('d_list '),('d_list'), ('d_list')"]

Expected result:
'd'
'e'
'f'
'g'
'h'
'i'
```

Comment: What have you tried? Stack Overflow is not meant to provide code, it is meant to answer a question about a specific error.

Comment: are u telling us or what?

Comment: So, your "load type" is which list to _exclude_?

Comment: Sorry @M-Chen-3, ombk, I have edited my question with what i have tried

Comment: Yes @RocketHazmat

Comment: what is really your question here ? please explain more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `d_list`, `m_list`, and `q_list` are global variables in the same file, you could do this:

**Input:**

```
d_list = ['a', 'b', 'c']
m_list = ['d', 'e', 'f']
q_list = ['g', 'h', 'i']
masterlist = ['d_list','m_list','q_list']

loadtype = 'd'
```

**Solution to run:**

```
g = globals()

[c for lst_name in masterlist if (not lst_name.startswith(loadtype)) 
                                     and (lst_name[1:] == '_list')
 for lst in g[lst_name] 
 for c in lst]
```

**Output:**

```
['d', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i']
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if this what you are searching for.
But this is a way to do what I think you want to do and you are getting strings because what you saved in your master list considered a string for python.

my example:

```
a = ["more", "explaining"]
b = ["is", "needed"]
master_list = [a, b]

print(master_list[1][1])

#or something like this:
for x in master_list[0]+ master_list[1]:
    print(x)

#or what I recommend using:
for x in a + b:
    print(x)
```